Meaning of bracket abstraction in combinatory logic
What does the bracket abstraction mean/represent in combinatory logic?
The method shown to me by textbook I am reading an by a very well made youtube video to convert a pointful definition of a combinator to a purely pointfree combination of combinators is as follows:
Using $SKIBC$ as a basis, let $Z$ be some combinator such that $Zabc\ldots wx=z$ where $z$ is some combinator expression. $Z$ can written as $Zabc{\ldots}w=[z]_x$ where $[z]_x$ can be substituted for using the following rules:
$[x]_x = I$
$[f]_x = K f \text{ if }f \text{ does not contain }x$
$[fx]_x = f \text{ if }f \text{ does not contain }x$
$[fg]_x = B f [g]_x \text{ if }f\text{ does not contain }x\text{ but g does}$
$[fg]_x = C [f]_x g \text{ if }f\text{ does contain }x\text{ but g does not}$
$[fg]_x = S [f]_x [g]_x \text{ if both }f\text{ and }g\text{ contain }x$
The substitution rules make sense to me, but I just don't understand what $[z]_x$ represents?

The idea here is that we can think of a combinator as a function.  For example, $I$ is the identity function, and $S$ is the function which takes three arguments $x,y,z$ and computes $$x\ z\ (y\ z).$$
The bracket abstraction is a method for taking an expression that defines a function, and finding a $SKIBC$ combinator that computes that function of whatever it is applied to.
For example, suppose we want to find an $SKIBC$ term $Z$ such that  $$Z\ x\ y \Rightarrow x\ (x\ y).$$  We can use the bracket abstraction to compute one.  First we eliminate variable $y$:
$$ \begin{array}{rl}
Z\ x = & [ Z\ x\ y]_y \\
&[x\ (x\ y)]_y \\
& B\ x\ [x\ y]_y \\
& B\ x\ x\\
\end{array}
$$
And in fact, if we apply $B\ x\ x$ to $y$ we get $B\ x\ x\ y \to x\ (x\ y)$.
This is not yet a combinator, though; we still need to eliminate $x$:
$$ \begin{array}{rl}
Z = & [Z\ x]_x \\
& [(B\ x)\ x]_x \\
& S\ [B\ x]_x\ [x]_x \\
& \mathbf{S\  B\ I} \\
& \end{array}
$$
$Z = S\ B\ I$ is the answer.  It takes two arguments $x, y$ and yields $x\ (x\ y)$. Observe:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
Z\ x\ y & = \\
\mathbf{S\ B\ I\ }x\ y & \Rightarrow \\
B\ x\ (I\ x)\ y & \Rightarrow\\
B\ x\ x\ y & \Rightarrow\\
x\ (x\ y)
\end{array}
$$
as desired.
The existence of this method shows that $SKIBC$ comprise what's called a "complete basis": every combinator can be written as a suitable composition of $S,K,I,B,$ and $C$.
